# Using clip in batch file makes strange result when copying an image

Tags: batch, windows-11, clipboard

I'm trying to copy an image file (`.jpg`) to clipboard using batch file, so then my macro can paste it using simple key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

The problem is, that after doing command:

```
clip < img.jpg
```

The result in clipboard is:

```
╪ р
```

How to use it correctly, so my image will appear in clipboard correctly, or what other methods I can use?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no native way to copy a file to clipboard from CMD prompt/batch file. See https://serverfault.com/questions/162273/how-to-send-a-file-into-clipboard-from-command-line-cli for third-party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *...or other methods I can use?*
> Use **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

---

## PowerShell :

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\The\Full\Path\To\File.eXt' | Set-ClipBoard

# Or...

gci 'C:\The\Full\Path\To\File.eXt' | scb
```

---

> *...or other methods I can use?*
> Or from **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**/**[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)**
> invoke **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**:

---

## cmd/bat:

```
PowerShell.exe -Nol -NoP -Ex -By -c "Get-ChildItem 'C:\The\Full\Path\To\File.eXt' | Set-ClipBoard"

:: Or...

PowerShell.exe -Nol -NoP -Ex -By -c "gci 'C:\The\Full\Path\To\File.eXt' | scb"
```

---

- An **[A-Z](https://ss64.com/ps/)** Index of Windows **[PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.3)** commands
- **[`Get-ChildItem` | `gci`](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)**
- **[`Set-ClipBoard` | `scb`](https://ss64.com/ps/set-clipboard.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want an image in `CF_DIB` [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) - viewable in clipboard history of some programs and pasteable in more apps, but not a file - you can use:

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -Assembly System.Drawing

$image = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('C:\full\path\img.jpg')
[Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetImage($image)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33055523/7264739)